# htaccess rewrite - removing the last part from url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to add RewriteRule to my htaccess to help me redirect From this (where the last two parts always changed according to what I request):

http://hbrarabic.com/people/xxx/yyy

to this:

http://hbrarabic.com/people/xxx/

so what I wrote is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (.*)/people/(.*)
RewriteRule ^people/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /people/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it dosen't work!
Can someone please help me figure out the problem

Comment: Is `people` a real directory?

Comment: @anubhava no .. (people) here is just an example about what I want .. so (people) never change .. but the last two ones are according to what I request.

Comment: The RewriteCond seems superfluous, the RewriteRule can check if the requested path matches the pattern by itself. Explain what “not working” actually means. No redirect at all? Landing in the wrong location? 404? …?

Comment: some parts of the url would be written with arabic character .. will this be a problem?

Comment: @misorude .. yes it's Not redirect at all

Comment: _“some parts of the url would be written with arabic character .. will this be a problem?”_ - well `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is probably not gonna match those …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(people/[^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```